# How do I know if the dispatch is called in redux even when props are unchanged?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a login page and I am sending login details to server on submitting the form.

The server either responds with an access token or error message.

In both case I am dispatching either loginSucess or loginFailure respectively and setting the isLoggedIn Property in state accordingly.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any) {
    // if (hasPropChanged("isLoggedIn", this.props, prevProps)) {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.props;
    if (isLoggedIn) this.props.history.push("/admin");
    else {
      notification.open({
        message: "Login error",
        description: "Invalid login credentials"
      });
    }
    // }
  }
```

But the problem is that if user sends invalid credentials for the first time the store is updated and I can show a notification on front end. But when isLoggedIn prop is not changed (user sends invalid credentials multiple times in a row) The component is not re-rendered or updated again. How do I detect when the api response has been received and dispatch is called? and show notification accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional prop (typically called `error` or similar) to model this state. Then it's pretty straightforward, you can set `error` to true or save a string with an error message. Alternatively, show the notification from your redux action, not from the component.

Answer (score 0):

react compare `prevProps` and `currentProps`, if there are not any change it will not update a component, to override that behavior use :

[shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

by implementing this method you can return true to update a component even if props are same, in your case it's `isLoggedIn`

Answer (score 0):

I agree to timotgl's answer, but I believe you need some more explanation.

In my opinion, You have 2 choices:

1. You should change `isLoggedIn`, or some other redux state, whenever the API call is done. The part where you say *" when `isLoggedIn` prop is not changed (user sends invalid credentials multiple times in a row) "* is giving me the idea that you are not changing the redux state on each API call. So, you should have redux states which tells if the API call is a success or not(for eg, `isSuccess`), and change it accordingly for each API call.

   2. You should handle this in your action itself, where you make the API call. Right when you know if each API call is a success or failure, you should show the notification there.

In my opinion, go for option 2. Less conditions and less state changes, I guess.

Hope you are dealing with something related to what I'm talking about, and hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You need to look in reducer store, if you have not mutate your state then it will not reflect here. so one every background server call complete you must mutate your state object, event if it has the same value.
On every submit click, send a random number in your payload and on complete you send back that same random number back to component as your store property and save in some hidden input.

Comment: How can I mutate the state, even if isLoggedIn stays false.

Comment: This is nonsense, you don't need to mutate anything if there is no difference in the new state.